# Computer hangs on motherboard splash screen, except when I let it rest for 5~10 minutes!

Tags: motherboard, freeze

I'm using an Asus motherboard and I have ubuntu 10.10 installed.

Recently I updated ubuntu 10.10 (update manager). After rebooting the computer, it started hanging out in the motherboard splash screen.

I think it may be just coincidence, since it hangs in the motherboard splash screen, the issue may be caused by hardware problems.

The weird thing is that the computer do start if I let it rest for 5~10 minutes.
- It never freezes while I'm on ubuntu splash page or inside the OS.
- I removed the video card long time ago.
- This has append to me 10 times so far.
- The weather is very cold. So I don't think it is overheating.

What could be the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Hit Esc on the splash screen and, if your BIOS is like many others, it'll display the text screen behind it, showing you exactly where it is freezing.

Specific things that can cause this:

- motherboard defects such as burnt caps, etc.
- failing or incorrectly installed hard drive
- failing or incorrectly installed optical drive
- scsi or other expansion card having issues during boot
- usb device connected that isn't quite mass-storage device compilant

In any event it wouldn't hurt to check the Asus website for BIOS updates as well.